# C# Excel Generation - Range Copy (undesired behavior) using last cell as first cell of correct data

Tags: c#, excel, copy, range

```
List<someClass> aList = new List<someClass>();

...

XLWorkbook workbook = new XLWorkbook();
IXLWorksheet worksheet = workbook.AddWorksheet("Data");
worksheet.Hide();
workbook.CalculateMode = XLCalculateMode.Manual;

var data = aList.ToArray();
var firstCell = worksheet.Cell(1, 1);
var lastCell = worksheet.Cell(numRows, numColumns); // numRows = 150, numColumns = 8
var writeRange = worksheet.Range(firstCell, lastCell); //firstCell = A1, LastCell = H150
writeRange.Value = data;

workbook.SaveAs(mySavePath);
```

This bit of code is meant to copy the data in aList into a new excel document, only, instead of starting at cell A1(1,1) and ending at cell H150 it copies the value from cell 1 into all of the cells between A1 and H299, the row values that should be in row 1 into column H-O from row 1-150, and finally my correctly grouped data from H150-O299.

Basically, my data starts at the offset of the range instead of filling in the range, and everything above and left of that range is default copied (garbage) data. someClass is just a public class with public fields for ints and strings.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening and how I can correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a solution, I found that using the same index for first and last cell will properly input my data, however why Range does not work as (assumed) intended has yet to be answered.

```
var firstCell = worksheet.Cell(1, 1);
var writeRange = worksheet.Range(firstCell, firstCell); //firstCell = A1, LastCell = H150
```

This will work as intended. I've completely removed lastCell as it is unnecessary.